# Merge [file-io-permissions] and [file-permissions]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I think [file-permissions](/questions/tagged/file-permissions) and [file-io-permissions](/questions/tagged/file-io-permissions) (and the badly-named [fileiopermission](/questions/tagged/fileiopermission)) mean pretty much the same thing. Do you think so too?